# How to reverse the order of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

My answer to part (a) is the blue region below:

[image]

My answer to part (b) is $\int_{0}^{2} \int_{y^2}^{4} \frac{x}{1+y^5} dxdy$

However I'm not sure it's correct. Could somebody please check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part (a), $y$ runs from $\sqrt x$ to $2$ so the appropriate region is the rectangle minus the blue region.

To reverse the order of integration, note that:

- $x$ runs from $0$ to $y^2$
- $y$ runs from $0$ to $2$

So

$$I=\int_{0}^{2}{\int_{0}^{y^2}{\frac{x}{1+y^5}\: dx\:dy}}$$

Your answer for part (b) was consistent with the fact that your interpretation of the region as the blue area, so this was the only error.

Comment: Note that Tonelli's theorem makes this interchange of integration order valid.